# Error from urlopen "code for hash not found" on linux

Tags: python, hash, urlopen

I've tried a couple of searches and I don't think this has been asked, but if this is a duplicate please forgive me. I'm trying to use urllib on python-2.7 to read from a web page. Very simple application, all I want to do is get some text from a page. Unfortunately the following code:

```
import urllib
address = "http://google.co.uk"
page = urllib.urlopen(address)
```

returns an error talking about the "hash code" not being found:

```
 ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
```

I've tried a lot of Google searching but nothing that's turned up so far has been very useful. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to install the openssl libraries and recompile the hash module in python; without openssl those hash formats are not supported.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters, I have found them thanks to the link provided by ajon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following page explains the package you need to install:

http://new2python.blogspot.com/2012/07/errorrootcode-for-hash-sha224-was-not.html

In summary:
You need to install hashlib library using the following commands:

```
tar xvfz hashlib-20081119.tar.gz
cd hashlib-20081119
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, even if it does rely on the link. The solution outlined on the page (go to http://code.krypto.org/python/hashlib/, and install the tar.gz using  
`tar xvfz hashlib-20081119.tar.gz; 
 cd hashlib-20081119; 
 python setup.py install` 
 solved the problem.